# Common holder variable for Android RecyclerView Multiviews in onBindViewHolder function

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new to android so please bear with me.

I have a multi view recycler view and I am using onClick interface with it. Since I have more than 10 views and to avoid repeated code in onBindViewHolder function I am working around to find a solution to have common holder instance.

Current code:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
...

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Model getData = data.get(position);

    if(getData.getMessageType().equals("Image")){
        ImageHolder mHolder = (ImageHolder) holder;
        // OnClick Event
    } else if(getData.getMessageType().equals("Video")){
        VideoHolder mHolder = (VideoHolder) holder;
        // OnClick Event
    }

    // *** I need to perform OnClick Event Here for all conditions
}

public static class ImageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    View card;
    public ImageHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        card = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageHolder);
    }
}

public static class VideoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    View card;
    public VideoHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        card = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoHolder);
    }
}

...
```

But the problem is, I can't instantiate a holder variable as Class name differs for every view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use `setOnClickListener` in `onBindViewHolder` method using `holder` instance, it will provide root element of the child rendered as `itemView`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Model getData = data.get(position);

    if(getData.getMessageType().equals("Image")){
        ImageHolder mHolder = (ImageHolder) holder;
        // OnClick Event
    } else if(getData.getMessageType().equals("Video")){
        VideoHolder mHolder = (VideoHolder) holder;
        // OnClick Event
    }
    //handles click of all the item types
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried that already tried that. If I use `holder.itemView`, I can't get reference to views inside it. Example: `holder.card`.

Comment: at some point you need to check condition and cast ViewHolder safely to access views specific to that